# Drag and Drop file uploader with multiple instance on a single page

Tags: php, jquery, file-upload, drag-and-drop

I need multiple instances of drag and drop file upload options on single page. 
I searched but couldn't find the one.
Can anyone of you please guide me towards some useful resource.

I tried with many drag and drop libs. They all are working fine with single drag and drop instance.But when I try to make it work for more than one g and drop instance. It doesn't work.

Comment: Have you tried with [Dropzone](https://github.com/enyo/dropzone) ?

Comment: http://www.9lessons.info/2012/09/multiple-file-drag-and-drop-upload.html

Comment: Thanks for your response. No, but I have started with it.

Answer (score 2):

I think this will help you.
https://github.com/valums/file-uploader

It has drag and drop and allows multiple instances.

Answer (score 0):

[jQuery filedrop plugin](https://github.com/weixiyen/jquery-filedrop) should work with multiple instances on the same page, so long as you initiate it multiple times, referencing separate DOM elements for each instance.